# React Native Marketing Cloud Sdk Status showing Not opted in

Tags: marketing-cloud, mobilepush-android, react-native-marketingcloudsdk

[image]

I am trying to implement marketing cloud SDK (8.0.0) in react native 0.68. SDK initialized successfully. but the status shows as Not Opted in. I don't know how to resolve this.

Notification not receiving in the android and ios.

can any one help me to resolve this?

Comment: Open a support ticket.